# rename files with certain characters with cmd

Tags: windows, cmd, rename

I found no other posts about this particular need.
Example:

> Naruto NA - 480p.mp4

I want to erase the "NA"
so it will be

> Naruto - 480p.mp4

I tried with

```
for /f "tokens=1*delims=NA" %%a in ('dir /b "*NA*.*"') do ren "%%aNA%%b" "%%a%%~xb"
```

but the output is

> Naruto .mp4

not only "- 480p" is gone, but there's a space between Naruto and the .mp4

Comment: You could use string substitution for this, but 1st this is case insensitive and 2nd requres a normal string (and in a code block also delayed expansion) and 3rd you'll need context as otherwise the `Na` from `Naruto` would also be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions possible.

The first one works as long as no file name contains one or more `!`:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%I in ("* NA -*") do (
    set "FileName=%%~nI"
    ren "%%I" "!FileName:NA -=-!%%~xI"
)
endlocal
```

The file name of current file is assigned without file extension to environment variable `FileName`. Before execution of command **REN** a string substitution is done by Windows command processor to replace case-insensitive all occurrences of `NA -` by just `-` in file name to remove the not wanted part of the file name.

The problem is the line `set "FileName=%%~nI"` which results in file name referenced with `%%~nI` containing one or more exclamation marks that Windows command processor parses this command line once again after replacing `%%~nI` by file name of current file and interprets each `!` as begin/end of an environment variable referenced delayed.

The second solution works also for file names with exclamation marks:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for %%I in ("* NA -*") do (
    set "FileName=%%~nI"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    ren "%%I" "!FileName:NA -=-!%%~xI"
    endlocal
)
endlocal
```

The assignment of file name of current file to environment variable `FileName` is done while delayed environment variable expansion is disabled and so `!` is interpreted as literal character. Then [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) is enabled to be able to use the string substitution before renaming the file and restoring previous local environment.

One more solution for renaming `Naruto NA - 480p.mp4` to `Naruto - 480p.mp4` is:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "* NA -*" /A-D-H /B 2^>nul') do for /F "eol=| tokens=1,2* delims= " %%A in ("%%~nxI") do ren "%%I" "%%A %%C"
endlocal
```

The outer **FOR** with option `/F` and a string in round brackets enclosed in straight single quotes runs in a separate command process started with `cmd.exe /C` in the background the command line:

```
dir "* NA -*" /A-D-H /B 2>nul
```

**DIR** searches in current directory for

- non-hidden files because of option `/A-D-H` (attribute not directory and not hidden)
- matching the wildcard pattern `* NA -*` and
- outputs in bare format line by line to handle **STDOUT** just the file names with file extension without path because of option `/B`.

**DIR** could also output an error message to handle **STDERR** in case of no non-hidden file found matching the wildcard pattern. This error message is redirected with `2>nul` to device **NUL** to suppress it.

Read the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

**FOR** captures all lines output to handle **STDOUT** of started command process and processes those lines after started `cmd.exe` terminated.

Empty lines are ignored by **FOR** which do not occur here.

Lines starting with `;` would be also ignored by **FOR** because of being default for option end of line. A file name can start with a semicolon. For that reason `eol=|` is used to define the vertical bar as end of line character which no file name can contain.

**FOR** would split up the line into substrings using normal space and horizontal tab as string delimiters and would assign just first space/tab delimited string to specified loop variable `I`. This behavior is not wanted here because of the file names contains multiple spaces. Therefore `delims=` is used to define an empty list of delimiters to turn off this string splitting behavior of command **FOR**.

The current file name assigned with the used options completely to specified loop variable `I` even on starting with `;` or with one or more spaces is processed as string by an inner **FOR**.

`eol=|` is used again on the inner **FOR** to avoid that a file name starting with `;` is not ignored. For the inner **FOR** splitting the file name string on spaces is wanted and so option `delims=`  is used to explicitly define just space as delimiter. The file name string should be split up on all occurrences of one or more spaces into three parts for `Naruto NA - 480p.mp4`:

1. First substring (token) `Naruto` should be assigned to specified loop variable `A`.
2. Second substring `NA` should be assigned to next loop variable `B` according to [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).
3. And rest of the string after all spaces after second space separated substring should be assigned to next but one loop variable `C` which is for this example `- 480p.mp4`.

This can be achieved with option `tokens=1,2*`.

On command **REN** the second substring is omitted and so the new file name is `Naruto - 480p.mp4`.

Of course this third solution does not work for example for a file with name `Naruto Uzumaki NA - 480p.mp4` because new name would be `Naruto NA - 480p.mp4` because of second space delimited substring is in this case `Uzumaki` and not `NA`.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `ren /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`